# PowerShell script for checking links in SharePoint Pages

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, csom

I'm trying to check whether every page on a given Sharepoint site contains certain URL with the following PowerShell script. It seems that the foreach loop does nothing at all. Whats should be the reason for this? Also I'm not getting any error messages. I successfully changed some of the list's properties but can't process the data.

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Mysite URL
$site = 'https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/contoso'
$urlToFind = "https://google.com"

#Admin User Principal Name
$admin = 'SampleUsername'

#Get Password as secure String
$Password = "SamplePassword"
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force

#Get the Client Context and Bind the Site Collection
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)

#Authenticate
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($admin , $SecurePassword)
$context.Credentials = $credentials

$list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle('Pages')
$context.Load($list)

$query = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery()
$Items = $list.GetItems($query)
$context.Load($Items)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$dataValues = @()
$items.GetEnumerator() | % { 
    $dataValues += $_.FieldValues 
}

$dataValues.Count #determine the amount of items

foreach($item in $dataValues)
{
    write-host "inside"
    write-host ""
    write-host "*** PAGE *** "$item.Url
    write-host ""
    $file = $item.File

    #get binary data, and decode into text
    $data   = $file.OpenBinary()
    $encode = New-Object System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
    $text   = $encode.GetString($data)

    if($text -match $urlToFind)
    {
        write-warning "FOUND BAD URL IN THIS DOCUMENT!"
    }
    else {
    write-host "nothing found"
    }
    #comment below to parse all pages
    #break

}
```

Comment: Not into Sharepoint at all, but since your `$urlToFind` contains characters that have special meaning in regex (and you are using regex with `-match`), you need to escape that: `[regex]::Escape($urlToFind)`

Answer (score 1):

We are unable to foreach $list.Items to $item.
We need query $Items by

```
$Items = $list.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())
```

Then

```
foreach($item in $Items)
```

Comment: first off all thanks for the much needed guidance. I have added a few lines of code which you can see in the first post and now the script starts and enters the loop. However the
`
$file = $item.File

    #get binary data, and decode into text
    $data   = $file.OpenBinary()
`
Is giving me the error that I can't call a method on a null-valued expression. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Please confirm you have file under the 'Pages' list

Comment: Yes, I have. I was able to extract them with JavaScript but PS is giving me this error.